# I have a page that contains both Flex and HTML at the same time. How do I make it cross resolution?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flex4, screen-resolution, resolution-independence

In one of my pages, I use a Flex 4 app in a column on the left, and then normal HTML in a column to the right. Is there anyway I can make it so that the ratio between the two columns is the same no matter the resolution?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It sounds as though you've tried something that didn't work as you expected ... if so, and if you can update your question with what didn't work, perhaps we can help you tune it so that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm if I understand you correctly, you should be able to give your `<object>` a width percentage.
This way you would be able to give your `<object>` a width of 50% and your right column a width of 50%.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Old way: Surround your page with a `<table>` with two `<td>` items, one for the Flex, the other for the HTML.  New way: surround each segment with a `<div>` with a id, and in your CSS, float the div's left/ right accordingly.

In either case, setting `<td width="50%">` or giving the div CSS property `width=50%;` should have worked.  But as Dave states, it sounds like you tried at least one of these methods without the expected result, so a little clip of your code would help the community help you.